# Currents injected in the grid, connecting a wind turbine

Tags: power-electronics, power-engineering, power-grid, windturbine

I'm studying the connection to the grid of a wind turbine through a three-phase inverter.

Now I understand that , in normal operating conditions, in the connection to the grid, the reference for id component of the current (considering the Park transformation) injected in the grid should be set by the active power controller (the DC voltage controller), while the iq component should be zero. Therefore we guarantee unitary power factor, and zero reactive power.

Now my doubts come when we are considering abnormal conditions. I read that to guarantee fault ride through we should now have the reference value of id set to zero and the value of iq now different than zero and set by the grid current controller. Is this correct? Why should we zero the active power? To stop injecting active power in the grid? But why managing the reactive power, how will that help to reestablish normal conditions again?

TL; DR: I don't understand the role reactive power has to manage abnormal condition in the connection to the grid and why set the active power to zero.

EDIT: I've read this in the book "Grid Converters for Photovoltaic and Wind Power Systems" by Remus Teodorescu

Comment: Where did you read that? Link (or book reference) in the question

Comment: @BrianDrummond reference added

Comment: @BrianDrummond can you help me?